# WEB API Startup class exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my web api, i have defined startup class as below,

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyProject.Cache.Startup))]

namespace MyProject.Cache
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            Configuration(app);
        }
    }
}
```

And when i run the project below exception is ocuring,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException'
>   occurred in MyProject.Cache.dll,

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `Configuration` method calls `Configuration` which calls `Configuration` which calls `Configuration` etc..

Comment: Circular dependency, u have the solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561242/an-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-stackoverflowexception-occurred-in-syste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be, that you have a endless recursion?

`Configuration(IAppBuilder app)` calls it self again.

Comment: Yes, It was my mistake. I suppose to call ConfigAuth